# NLog to WCF. Closing client throws SocketException on Server

Tags: wcf, nlog, socketexception

I've been struggling with this problem for a whole day and do not know how to fix it. I have tried various things to resolve the issue but I am at a loss.

I have a project where I am attempting to use the LogReceiverServer from NLog to send and receive messages between 2 PCs. [I followed this example here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/LogReceiverService-target). Everything actually works fine, my WCF service starts up correctly, my client starts up correctly, even the sending of the message to log from client to server works. But, when I shut the client down, I get SocketExceptions thrown by the server for each message that was transmitted. I know this is due to the channel not being closed properly by the client. I cannot find where I must close the channel to prevent the exceptions being thrown by my server. I have read that to manually close the channel I must use

```
Channel.Close();
```

would that be correct and where would I put that?

I want to prevent these SocketExceptions. I have found [this](http://burcakcakiroglu.com/?p=2083), but it does not seem to be the correct thing to do. Correct me if I am wrong, but would the solution not use the same principles?

Unless of course I am understanding this completely wrong...

Everything is done using the config files (App.Config and NLog.Config).

Here is my LogReceiverService Target from NLog.config:

```
<target xsi:type="LogReceiverService" 
        name="logreceiver" 
        endpointConfigurationName="LogReceiverClient" 
        endpointAddress="net.tcp://server:8888/NLogServices/LogReceiverServer/logreceiverserver" />
```

Here is my endpoint from my app.config:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://server:8888/NLogServices/LogReceiverServer/logreceiverserver" 
          binding="netTcpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="LogReceiverClient" 
          contract="NLog.LogReceiverService.ILogReceiverClient" 
          name="LogReceiverClient" />
```

Any help or advise would greatly be appreciated.

**EDIT: Extended on problem description**

OK, So first, here is the Service on my host pretty much as I got it from [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/LogReceiverService-target):

```
/// <summary>
/// Log service server object that logs messages.
/// </summary>
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class LogReceiverServer : ILogReceiverServer
{
    public void ProcessLogMessages(NLogEvents nevents)
    {
        var events = nevents.ToEventInfo("Client.");

        foreach (var ev in events)
        {
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(ev.LoggerName);
            logger.Log(ev);
        }
    }
}
```

I then created this class, where I inherit from LogReceiverWebServiceTarget and override `protected virtual WcfLogReceiverClient CreateWcfLogReceiverClient();` method. It is exactly the same as is found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Targets/LogReceiverWebServiceTarget.cs), except that I registered on the ProcessLogMessagesCompleted event where I close the 'client':

```
    [Target("wcftarget")]
    public class WcfTarget : LogReceiverWebServiceTarget
    {
        protected override WcfLogReceiverClient CreateWcfLogReceiverClient()
        {
            WcfLogReceiverClient client;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EndpointConfigurationName))
            {
                // endpoint not specified - use BasicHttpBinding
                Binding binding;

                if (UseBinaryEncoding)
                {
                    binding = new CustomBinding(new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(), new HttpTransportBindingElement());
                }
                else
                {
                    binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                }

                client = new WcfLogReceiverClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(EndpointAddress));
            }
            else
            {
                client = new WcfLogReceiverClient(EndpointConfigurationName, new EndpointAddress(EndpointAddress));

        /*commenting this out causes multiple socket exceptions on host*/
                client.ProcessLogMessagesCompleted += client_ProcessLogMessagesCompleted; 
            }
            return client;
        }

        private void client_ProcessLogMessagesCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            WcfLogReceiverClient client = sender as WcfLogReceiverClient;

            if (client.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                (sender as WcfLogReceiverClient).Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The Logger in NLog.config is:

```
<logger name="*" writeTo="logreceiver" minlevel="Info" />
```

So then if I try to log like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        logger.Info("foo");

    }
}
```

my host gives prints this to Debug:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
```

Will this have any impact on performance of the host over a long period of time?

Comment: Hi @pjdupreez, could you supply us with a demo-app to reproduce this?

Comment: Will do. What I have done though in the interim just to suppress multiple socket exceptions was to create my own Target inheriting from  LogReceiverWebServiceTarget and then register on  the ProcessLogMessagesCompleted where I close the connection after transmission. I only get one socketexception now instead of one for each transmission. I'll get some code ready and post it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/commit/138fd2ec5d94072a50037a42bc2b84b6910df641